# Xcode 4.4.1 (LLVM) linker takes huge amounts of memory and then asserts

Tags: xcode4, llvm, ld, osx-mountain-lion

Is it just my imagination, or have others noticed that the linker included with the latest Xcode from the Mac App Store (4.4.1) has started using much more memory than earlier versions? I mean like 6 GB of memory or more. This is when producing i386 shared libraries from some hundreds of object files, some of which, or all, might be compiled with -g. Is it doing some kind of expensive link-time-optimization nowadays that earlier linker versions didn't do? How can I turn that off?

Sorry for not being able to be more specific... I have just started investigating this. So far my MacBook Pro, running 10.8, has managed to get totally hung a couple of times while a build of the software in question has been running, presumably thanks to running out of disk & swap space (yeah, I am a bit tight on disk space), so that only a long power button press has been effective...

Actually in some cases the linker ends up getting an assertion error:

```
Assertion failed: (counter() < 0xffff), function nextCounter, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-133.3/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 99.
0  0x10adb2280  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10adf2f11  ld::tool::InputFiles::findDylib(char const*, char const*) + 321
2  0x10aded00a  mach_o::dylib::File<x86>::processIndirectLibraries(ld::dylib::File::DylibHandler*, bool) + 138
3  0x10adf36b4  ld::tool::InputFiles::createIndirectDylibs() + 676
4  0x10adf4b2a  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&) + 874
5  0x10adff34c  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 204
6  0x10adb2649  main + 585
```

Comment: Have you reported this to apple bugtracker?

Comment: Yes, and attached the "linker snapshot". So hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Any feedback/information on this so far?

Comment: @tml did they ever respond? I'm encountering this reproducibly (but in a huge repro, so not really easy to send them)

Comment: I don't have the problem any more, and Xcode is now at 6.0... This question is totally irrelevant by now.